# NoMethodError in Clients#index - Of some reason i can't find the issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I am getting the error message `NoMethodError in Clients#index`, and Rails won't show me the client orders for some reason. I can't locate the issue.

This is the message I get when I click at the link:

```
Showing /home/kim91/Dev/Dolls-1/app/views/clients/index.html.slim where line #34 raised:

undefined method `orders' for #<Client id: 1, navn: "Bo Petersen", nummer: "", cvr_nr: 25621603, telefon: "", email: "", fax: "", kontakt: "", client_type_id: nil, beskrivelse: "Ophørt - Oprydning i foråret 2022\n", created_at: "2022-03-22 02:22:50.590978000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-03-22 02:22:50.590978000 +0000", subcontractor_cvr_nr: nil, type: nil, subcontractor_id: nil>''
```

This is the code:

```
h1 Listing Clients

table.table.table-striped.table-hover.datatable
  thead.thead-dark
    tr
      th Navn
      /th Nummer
      th Cvr nr
      /th Telefon
      th Email
      /th Fax
      /th Kontakt
      /th Client type
      /th Beskrivelse
      th Loc Cnt
      th Order Cnt
      th
      th
      th

  tbody
    - @clients.each do |client|
      tr
        td = client.navn
        /td = client.nummer
        td = client.cvr_nr
        /td = client.telefon
        td = client.email
        /td = client.fax
        /td = client.kontakt
        /td = client.client_type&.name
        /td = client.beskrivelse
        td = client.collection_locations.size
        td = client.orders.size
        td = link_to 'Show', client
        td = link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client)
        td = link_to 'Destroy', client, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete

br

= link_to 'New Client', new_client_path
```

Is there anyone that can help locate the issue here??

[Error message in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNOYR.png)

[Page working successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRsn5.png)

Comment: `undefined method 'orders' for #<Client.....` -- As the error message suggests, this is the issue. This is what you need to understand, and fix. **What is the `Client` model** (`./app/models/client.rb`)? What do you expect `Client#orders` to be? Potentially you're missing a line like `has_many :orders` in the model?

Comment: The issue is probably unrelated to your view. In `rails console` fetch that client via `client = Client.find(1)` and try to execute `client.orders` – do you get the same error? If so, this indicates that the `orders` method isn't defined.

Comment: Can you add your `Client` model with associations?